# DirectoryNotificationControl not notifying certain changes?

Tags: c#, active-directory, notifications

I'm writing a C# application that monitors Active Directory for certain changes, and synchronize those to another system. I'm using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryNotificationControl from C# for this purpose so I don't have to poll AD for changes.

Works well in most scenarios. If I edit the user and adds the user to a group, I get notified. But if I edit a group and add a user to that group, I'm not notified about the user change. I'm notified about the group change though, but then I have to scan the groups members and maintain a crosscheck list and compare. Which doesn't scale.

Any ideas on how I can get notified more precisely about group membership changes in Active Directory?

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: I know this is going back now, but do you have the base code of that notification check. Trying the same thing and get no response for any changes at all.

Comment: No, and also, someone later told me that "friends don't let friends use DirectoryNotificationControl", so there's that. It's not scalable. Consider using DirSync instead.

Answer (score 3):

Group membership is stored on the group. There is no modification to the user when you add them to a group. The display of group membership on the properties of the user is an abstraction via the `memberOf` attribute which is calculated on the fly when requested.

Answer (score 2):

Full agree with @Brian Desmond, you can find the source information of what he is talking about in [User Security Attributes Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article (look for memberof). You can also read that you can get more informations in connecting to a Global Catalog

WMI is perhaps a second solution you can dig in.It exists AD WMI Providers. [Using WMI to Monitor AD](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-management-instrumentation-wmi/using-wmi-to-monitor-ad) gives you some clues about that. This article don't do more than what you get so far, but I think that with WMI events you can create the notifications you need. You can find Microsoft informations about this begining in [Monitoring Active Directory Health](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180912.aspx), especialy Active [Directory WMI Providers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180914.aspx).